# Error with QGIS and Grass Tools

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, error, tools

I wanted to use the r.viewshed tool in QGIS. Everytime I want to start the tool there is a error (german):

Dieser Algorithmus kann nicht ausgeführt werden run :-( 
GRASS GIS 7 ist anscheinend nicht richtig auf dem System installiert und konfiguriert. Bitte vor der Ausführung von GRASS GIS 7-Algorithmen installieren.

Do I have to install GRASS 7 to use the tools?

I am using a Mac with 10.13 and QGIS 2.18

[image]

Comment: Yes, Grass needs to be installed. Qgis just wraps these functions by a dialog.

Comment: For download, see https://grass.osgeo.org/download/software/mac-osx/